# VBA Application worksheet function error:1004

Tags: vba

I was trying to add index/match values to a textbox , when a combobox value is selected. I get error :1004. What I am doin wrong? Thanks

```
Private Sub cmbStkItem_Change()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    
    Set sh = Sheets("suppliersdb")

    txtStkSupName.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(sh.Range("B2:B100"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.cmbStkItem.Value, sh.Range("c2:c100"), 0), "")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Break it down by assigning this to a variable first: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.cmbStkItem.Value, sh.Range("c2:c100"), 0)` - also can you assign **""** to the combobox value?

Comment: Thanks, the "" was a typing error. It works now. I have cut it short assigning variables.